# Node.js graphql refetch after mutation

Tags: node.js, graphql, react-apollo

Im used to making queries and mutations in the frontend in react, however for my app right now i am making the mutations on node.js since i need to run my data trough some functions.

I am using

> graphql-request

to do my queries and mutations, i am unsure though how i can make a refetch on the backend so that it will be visual on the client side.

```
const handleNewSongMutation = async (props) => {
  const variables = {
    artist: props[0].artist,
    title: props[0].title,
    url: props[0].url,
    pictures: props[0].pictures ? props[0].pictures : 'empty',
  }
  return await request(`${port}`, addSongMutation, variables).then(async data => {
    return data;
  });
};
```

This is a mutation that i will run, what i would like to do is that after this mutation was run that it will make a refetch.

Could someone advice me if this is possible, or if this can be done on the client side.

Comment: The best way to handle this is to modify the mutation to return the new data state. If you're the maintainer of the GraphQL server, you can add the data fetch to the mutation resolver so the Client only needs to call the mutation and the resolver will handle the underlying multiple steps. That is one of the benefits of the GraphQL abstraction over the data services/stores.

Comment: Do you mean in in my resolvers for the mutation that i would do a query for the songs after the song was saved to the database?

The only thing my client side is doing now is to fetch all items once it launches, and my node.js server is doing the mutation only.

When i upload a item from my client its trough a http request that goes to my /upload route in node.js where it then makes the mutation